# ChartJS: How to Increase the space from the chart and the labels above?

Tags: javascript, layout, charts, chart.js

I would like to increase the space between the Chart itself and the labels above it with a Chart Code I got from ChartJs. The chart is a polarareachart which has labels above.

Somewhere I read that this doesn't work. Is that true? Or can somebody help my with that? I am new to JavaScript and only know the basics :(

I also already had a look at the youTube Channel of ChartJS but couldn't find anything about it.

updated version of fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/63c5mf1t/1/

Already tried this:

```
const options = {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        top: 30, // Hier kannst du den gewünschten Abstand einstellen
      },
    },
```

```
const options = {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {    // Pop-Up Einstellungen
        backgroundColor: '#78a2d3' // Hintergrund
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
        labels: {
          color: '#ffffff', // Labels über dem Chart, Schriftfarbe weiß
          padding: 20, // Abstand zwischen den Labels selbst
        },
      },
    },
```

Comment: Can you create reproducible example here in inline editor or in jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure. Here is the complete code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/63c5mf1t/1/. Just focus on the chart and the Labels. Normally the Website would have a background etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't do this ***out-of-the-box***. The [official documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html), on the legend plugin states at the end of all properties:

> *...
> If you need more visual customizations, please use an [HTML legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/legend/html.html).*

With this you should beable to do all the formating you need *(with html, js and css)*.

**Update:**

*(Of course you could use a different plugin, or code your own.)*

In the following demo, I combined the code of [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87rnMzENg3U&t=390s) (you posted in the comment) with your [demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/63c5mf1t/1/):

**Here the demo:**
*(I stripped all properties, lines of code, that are not relevant for the example, to keep it small and lean.)*

```js
// - START - custom plugin 
  const legendMargin = {
      id: 'legendMargin',
      beforeInit(chart, legend, options){
          let fitValue = chart.legend.fit;
          chart.legend.fit = function fit(){
              fitValue.bind(chart.legend)();
              return this.height += options.paddingTop;
          }
      },
      defaults: {
          paddingTop: 0 // <-- default padding
      }
  };
// - END - custom plugin 

  const chartData = {
    2010: [107, 90, 200],
  };

  const data = {
    datasets: [{
      data: [107, 500, 200],
      // ...
    }],
    labels: ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow'],
  };

  const options = {
    plugins: {
      legendMargin: {  // <-- Set option of custom plugin
        paddingTop: 50 // <---- override the default value
      },
      // ...
    },
    // ...
  };

const chart = document.getElementById('chart1');
new Chart(chart, {
  type: 'polarArea',
  data: data,
  options: options,
  plugins: [legendMargin],  // <-- Add custom plugin
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div style="width:500px;height:350px">
   <canvas id="chart1" ></canvas>
<div>
```

Comment: But here it works...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87rnMzENg3U&t=390s

Comment: In this video a plugin is written to override the legend functionality, That is always a option, but writing a `plugin` is  not really a **out-of-the-box** functionality. But it hat works for you why not use that code?

Comment: I tried but its not working in my case :((

Comment: @KajaS. I updated my answer, with a demo. It should work. _Viel Glück_

Comment: You can change the css styles of the `div` arround the chart, to make the whole chart area bigger. If that is not possible there is no easy fix _(atleast I don't know any)_, since the chart area is limited and, the custom plugin, makes the ledgend bigger, so less space for the chart. That's why I personally would opt for the, from chartjs recommend option, to use the _HTML legend_.

Comment: yes now it works, thaaank you @winner_joiner!!! Ahh just deleted my comment because I already found out by myself how to increase the size of the chart but again thank you very much!